# How do I integrate NuGet into my Bamboo Build Plan?

Tags: continuous-integration, nuget, bamboo

Our build plans for Sitecore (.Net) websites are currently using Bamboo as the build plan master for continuous integration process.  Bamboo supports building a .Net project, and that .Net project contains references to several Sitecore binaries.

I have used NuGet as an artifact repository, mostly because that seemed to be the one most people were using.

So, now that I have a nuget repository, am [hosting my own feed](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds), and have added the Nuget package to my project (I just installed the package of binaries I created), what more do I need to do?

Should the build call out something special, or am I done?  I guess I'm just nervous that bamboo isn't talking directly to my repository....

In the closest analogy I have, namely a Maven/Archiva combo, the maven plan specifically references the artifacts in archiva, pulling the correct version as needed.  Does NuGet do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nuget 1.4+ supports "Package restore" which embeds a call to an MsBuild task in the project file. When the packages are not available it will automatically restore them while building the project.

Answer (score 9):

Since there have been some new developments in the NuGet package restore approach, I thought I'd post an update on this topic. We're using Visual Studio 2012. I wanted to be able to run MSBuild and make sure that it would first restore NuGet packages without setting "Package restore" to true in the config. Here's what I did (inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/23935892/414376):

1. Upgraded NuGet in my solution to a version later than 2.7 (2.8.3 in my case; this seems like an optional step)
2. Installed NuGet.exe on the build server
3. Added NuGet.exe to my remote agent so that it could be run as a command from Bamboo
4. Added the NuGet command to my build plan with argument `restore` (so that the command will be `nuget restore`); I've placed it right before my MSV Build task.

That was all I needed to get this to work properly according to the latest guidelines.

Comment: Hi Pascal, a little late to make a comment to this one now that I am needing some help in getting nuget packages out on the build server. The build server has 2019 VS installed, and I have asked the administrator to install nuget.exe on the build server. Once he installs it, all I need to do is to create a command task that would run right before the MSBuild task, correct? I don't think I quite understood what you meants on adding a neget.exe to the remote agent. I believe when I create a command task, I see Nuget an option already...it could be this wasn't available in 2017 but now it is.

Comment: Hi @bladerunner. It's been quite a while since I've worked on this project. And I'm not with that organisation anymore. So I'm afraid I cannot help you any further other then saying that it is indeed very likely that things work a bit differently with the latest versions of the tools.

Comment: Hi @Pascal, not a problem. I was able to figure this out after working with somebody on the team. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is old news, but my packages are in \packages. No amount of "dotnet restore" would work, until I explicitly mentioned the packages folder.

```
dotnet restore --packages .\packages
```

restored them!

VS2019. just in case it's version specific.