# Jenkins, build server and nuget restore

Tags: git, jenkins, nuget, visual-studio-2015

Sorry in advance for the low level question but i'm very confused and this is new to me. 
I'm trying to configure a continuous integration environment in what I believe is a very classic way. 
I've got my source on gitlab, jenkins is the build agent and a fresh windows server 2012 as the actual build server. 
So far I'm able to start a build from jenkins and on the build server, the code is pulled from my git repo online, and attempt to build fails at that stage because...

Well I'm not too sure but in my understanding it's because the project has nuget dependencies that are not resolved (they're not included in the source control and I want to keep it that way).

Do I need to install/configure nuget client on the server and add a nuget restore on my jenkins build config ?

I'm on visual studio 2015 and the retore package option is not available, I saw some discussion giving workarounds but that involved editing the project file manually or things like that which I'd like to avoid to keep things simple.

Any hint or advice greatly appreciated.

Also good to point out that the build server does not have any install of visual studio, I'm attempting to build only relying on MSBuild and when I add unit test support in the future I'll go for a framework not relying on visual studio.

Many Thanks

Comment: I found my answer in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22300375/nuget-auto-package-restore-does-not-work-with-msbuild