# NuGet restore works, but compile fails on build server

Tags: msbuild, nuget

I am trying to build a .NET 4.6 project using MSBuild 15 on our build server (using CruiseControl).
The project has a NuGet package reference (to Oracle.ManagedDataAccess) and it gets restored correctly. 
However, the build task fails with the error "The type or namespace name 'Oracle' could not be found".

I have tried building the project in VS 2017 on the build server using the same account, and it works.
I expected MSBuild to retrieve the package contents from the same location, but apparently it can't. What could be the reason?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/22300375/7945578

Comment: It's not restore that fails, it is the build task after it.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to have been caused because MSBuild 14 was used in the build task instead of MSBuild 15. Not sure exactly why that made it fail, but it works now.