# NuGet client version requires 3.6.0 or above

Tags: .net, nuget

after several hours trying to install a Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore package to my solution , it says that i have to update NuGet version to 3.6.0 or above , but i couldnt. Despite of looking on the Internet , i couldnt update it , i would be pleased  if you guys give me a solution. The version of Visual Studio Community is 2015.

```
Install-Package : The 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.1' package requires NuGet client version '3.6.0' or above, but the current NuGet version is '3.4.4'.
```

Greetings, Ivan.

Comment: Why you couldn't update it? This might be helpful [How to upgrade NuGet with Visual Studio 2017?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51830790/how-to-upgrade-nuget-with-visual-studio-2017)